# How can i compare two lists and create new list with with new object

Tags: java, stream

I have 2 lists:

1 Lists contain the all Customers in DB, and the second list is contain only part of the customers from the DB:

```
List<Customers> allCustomers = findAll();

List<Customers> inUseCustomers = findAllCustomersInUse();
```

I have another object calls: CustomerDto

```
public class CustomerDto {

    private Customer _customer;
    private boolean _inUse;

    public CustomerDto(Customer customer, boolean inUse) {
        this._customer = customer;
        this._inUse = inUse;
    }
}
```

I want to create a new list of CustomerDto that contains all customers but for those customers that in use, their field "inUse" will be true, and the rest will be false.

how can I do that with stream in a clean way?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far and where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Man, I believe you could do something like this, if I got what you are trying to do and how your code might work:

```
List<CustomerDto> customerDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Customer customer : allCustomers) {
    CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto(customer, customer.isInUse());
    customerDtoList.add(customerDto);
}
```

Here you are simply instantiating a new CustomerDto object with the customer inside the allCustomers list, and the value of its variable "inUse". Then, this object is being added to the List object.

I don't know if I write it all correct, and perhaps you could also do some refactor, but as the other guy said above it would be easier if we know what you have already tried. I hope my answer can at least give you an idea of what to do :v.